# How can I create a plugin project in FL Studio and debug it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I have downloaded the SDK library from the official FL Studio website but don't know how to debug the code. Can you help me?

I set the debugger to the path C:\Program Files\Image-Line\FL Studio 21\FL64.exe, but it's not working when I run it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you written any code to debug yet? Because it looks like you're trying to attach the debugger to something which you've installed into `C:\Program Files`, which (probably) won't work because it's (probably) a release build which won't have the symbols which a debugger requires.

Comment: thank you, What can I do with it?